# How to move jpg images below specified size from one to another file by batch code?

Tags: image, batch-processing

I need to move jpg images below specified sizes from one folder to another by wirting batch code. I found out the code below to move images below 300x300 size to the file named 'FileName' but it does not work. Could you please advise me if you have?

```
find -iname \*.jpg | while read img; do anytopnm "$img" | pamfile | perl -ane 'exit 1 if $F[3]<300 || $F[5]<300' || mv "$img" ./FileName; done
```

Regards

Guvenc

Comment: "*but it does not work*" -- Please describe the failure mode you're seeing.

Comment: Huh? Make your mind up! Do you want to move images to another directory or rename them all as `./Filename`? I suspect you want to do `mkdir new` first, then use `... mv “$img” new ... `

Comment: What I am entirely trying to do is to determine the images below 300x300 and move it to a specified file by executing batch code. Please disregard the tasks regarding file(s).Do you have any idea?